# A better way of representing two extremely similar, yet different objects in Django?

Tags: django, database, data-modeling

so I'm trying to create a good way of modelling both "houses" and "house groups".

Houses and house groups are extremely similar in that they both carry a description and have related pricing information.

However, "bookings" can only be assigned to Houses and not to HouseGroups.

At the moment, my model looks like this:

```
class Houselike(models.Model):
    max_guests = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class House(Houselike):
    pass

class HouseGroup(Houselike):
    houses = models.ManyToManyField(House)
```

Semantically, this actually very close to what I want. However, in the database, this leads to there being two tables that both only have a single field "houselike_ptr_id" referring to the "Houselike" base object.

Checking whether a Houselike object is a House or a Housegroup thus involves looking in two different tables.

A more efficient alternative would be to do:

```
class Houselike(models.Model):
    max_guests = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_group = models.BooleanField()
    houses = models.ManyToManyField(House)
```

This results in only 1 extra field in the "houselike" table, and the other table containing the related houses is only hit if we actually look them up. This is the best solution from a storage point of view IMHO.

However, this isn't quite as good from a semantic point of view: Houses and Housegroups are similar, but different objects.

Also, this allows for stuff like housegroups containing other housegroups, non-groups containing houses, things I have to all check manually.

I also really like being able to explicitly work with `House` and `HouseGroup` objects. Representing them both with the same class just feels wrong.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that pricing information (as well as other entities) can be associated with either a House or a Housegroup, and is implemented (roughly) as follows:

```
class PricePeriod(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(Houselike, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    # Date of last departure date
    departure_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places=2)
```

This is why I don't simply make the Houselike an abstract model, because these other objects are related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is something called "single table inheritance", which is perfect in my case.

And, this being the Internet, there's an app for that: https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models

```
from typedmodels.models import TypedModel

# Create your models here.

class Houselike(TypedModel):
    max_guests = models.IntegerField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class House(Houselike):
    pass

class HouseGroup(Houselike):
    houses = models.ManyToManyField(House)
```

This resulted in pretty much exactly what I was asking: a single table in the database, and an explicit, semantically-correct model in Python/Django.

Now just I just need to fix my awful naming...